# C++ tightening function parameter type in subclass

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, interface

I have an abstract `class A` with a virtual function `void fnc(XX*)`
In it's subclass (`class B`) I would like to tighten the function argument type (I hope this is the correct word for it), so fnc would only accept `YY*`, which is a subclass of `XX`.

It does not work, because I get this error:

```
invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'C'
because the following virtual functions are pure within 'C':
virtual void A::fnc(XX*)
```

Code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class XX {};

class YY : public XX {};

class A {
public:
    virtual void fnc(XX*) = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void fnc(YY*) = 0;
};

class C : public B {
public:
    virtual void fnc(YY*) override {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    YY* yy = new YY();
    C* cc = new C();

    cc->fnc(yy);
}
```

Comment: if this were allowed, A's interface would be lying. An interface that lies is not useful to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Co-variant function parameter types aren't supported in C++.

It's not very supported in general as well, since it can easily violate the Liskov substitution principle.

But regardless, what's happening in your code, is that you overload the function. You add another pure virtual function that needs to be overridden. The original one remains unimplemented, and your compiler complains about it.